# How do weak attributes convert from ER diagram to relational schema?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd, relational-model

I am creating an ER diagram and relational schema for a school project. In my ER diagram, I have shown attributes like "street name" and "city" as weak attributes of another attribute "address." How would I convert this to a relational schema? Do weak attributes even appear in my relational schema?

[Part of my ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEDLJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to call `Billing Address` a composite attribute, and `City` a component attribute.

The term "weak" is used in ER diagrams to describe entity sets that include another entity set's key as part of its own. For example, if an `Invoice` is identified by an `Invoice_ID`, and contains `LineItems` that are identified by `Invoice_ID, Line_Number`, that would make `LineItem` a weak entity set, and `Line_Number` would be its weak key.

When converting composite/component attributes to a relational schema, the simplest approach is to use only the component attributes. This means the composite attributes are nothing more than a visual aid.